# regex.PatternSyntaxException meta character '*'

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String girdi = input.nextLine();
for(int i=1; i<girdi.length(); i+=1){
    if(girdi.charAt(i) == '*'){
        int temp1= girdi.charAt(i-1)-'0';
        int temp2= girdi.charAt(i+1)-'0';
        int temp3 = temp1 * temp2;
        String a = girdi.substring(i-1,i);
        String b = "" + temp3;                
        String a2 = girdi.substring(i+1,i+2);
        String b2 = girdi.substring(i , i+1); 
        girdi = girdi.replaceFirst(a,b);
        girdi = girdi.replaceFirst(b2, "");   
        girdi = girdi.replaceFirst(a2, "");     
    }
}
```

I am just trying to make multiplication

when I type something like that (3*5) give me that error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '*' near index 0

and when I am using backslah to escape :

```
if(s.charAt(i) == '\\*'){
```

I see unclosed character literal and illegal start of expression errors

what should I do?

Comment: No, it's not this part of the code doing that. No regexes here.

Comment: You're first example should not throw an exception, please [edit] your question to include your code in full.

Comment: Please edit your question and include *all* lines of the exception’s stack trace.

Comment: @Agarta what do you mean "give an input"? If `s` is `"4 * 5"`, you've still got no regexes in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Agarta you need to show a [mcve]. The code you have shown doesn't produce the error you describe.

Comment: @AndyTurner   now it has to give that error when you give to 3 *5 or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the Javadoc of [`String.replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

- The first parameter is a regular expression (meaning characters like `*` have special meaning);
- The second parameter is a regex replacement (meaning certain character sequences have special meaning, e.g. `\` and `$`).

If you want to pass in strings from an untrusted source (like user input), you need to quote them appropriately:

```
girdi = girdi.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(a), Matcher.quoteReplacement(b));
```

---

However, `String.replaceFirst` is not the right tool for this job. It won't work correctly if there is a match for the search string before the one you are really looking for.

The most straightforward modification to your code would be to use `String.substring` - you know exactly where the thing you want to replace is, so make use of that information:

```
girdi = girdi.substring(0, i-1) + temp3 + girdi.substring(i+2);
i
```

(This would replace the last 7 lines in the loop)

You can do this better again by using a `StringBuilder`, to avoid creating unnecessary strings in the loop.

However, this still wouldn't work in the case of multi-digit or negative numbers.